# Jmeter - executed a script with and without timer. but the result doesnt seem to work well

Tags: jmeter

i executed a script for login in Jmeter. 
User 1, rampup time 1, loop 5, cache and cookie manager added. Clear cache of each iteration checked.

without timer below are the time taken for a user in next iteration
[image]

after adding constant timerof 3000ms below are the values obtained.
[image]

can someone please explain the results after adding constant timer of 3000ms?
according to me the result should be approx. 2+30sec =around 32 sec foreach iteration.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter doesn't include [Pre-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) duration into [Sample Result](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) by default

If you want to include these 3 extra seconds added by the Timer put your Sampler under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller/) and tick both `Generate parent sample` and `Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample` boxes:

[image]

Comment: did the settings in transaction controller. below timings obtained. without timer :
00:00:02.276

00:00:02.064
00:00:02.073
00:00:02.238
with constant timer : 300 ms :: 00:00:03.980
00:00:03.834
00:00:03.861
00:00:03.923

Comment: with constant timer = **3000ms** below result obtained: : 00:00:12.790
00:00:12.624
00:00:12.674
00:00:12.650